# Computing probabilities of a formula

Tags: probability

I have a random variable $X$ has a cumulative distribution function $F$ defined by a formula:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if}\,\,x\lt2\\0,3,&\text{if}\,\,-2\le x<-0.5\\0.5,&\text{if}\,\,-0.5 \le x \lt 0.5\\0.8,&\text{if}\,\,0.5\le x\lt1\\1,&\text{if}\,\,k \ge 1\end{cases}$$

I would like to ask how to:

- compute the probability mass function of $X$
- calculate the probabilities: $P(-1 \lt X \lt 1)$, $P(-1 \le X \le 1 )$, $P(0 \lt X)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is a discrete distribution with range $-2, -0.5, 0.5, 1$ (I assume that's a typo in the first line, should be $x<-2$).  And $P(X=-2)=0.3$, $P(X=-0.5)=.2$, $P(X=0.5)=0.3$ and $P(X=1)=.2$.

Answer (score 0):

*How* you do it is straightforward: Graph the staircase function $F(x)$.  The probability mass function $f(x) \equiv P(X = x)$ is $0$ everywhere except for the upward steps in $F(x)$; at each $x$ where $F(x)$ has an upward step, $f(x)$ equals the size of that step.  This is because the cumulative distribution function is defined as $F(x) \equiv P(X \leq x)$, and therefore only increases at those points $x$ which represent values that $X$ can take on, by an amount equal to the probability of $X$ assuming that value.

You should obtain the function described by Gregory Grant in his answer.